# How client can edit Wordpress without breaking HTML?

Tags: wordpress, client, wysiwyg, edit

Usually I set up pages in Wordpress by putting all the HTML in and the client will edit the content in the WYSIWYG editor

This is great, until they accidentally delete a div or break something.

What is the correct way to go about this making it idiot proof, so that they can change titles, paragraphs etc without potentially deleting parts of the structure?

Answer (score 1):

If your client does not know HTML, and you know this going into the project, the only things he/she should be inputting in the page editor are words, uploaded media, and elements that can be inserted using the visual editor. It's a pain in the butt, but your theme should be the part that's "idiot proof".

Build your theme to wrap `the_content();` in a div, and style all the potential elements that can be input accordingly. Only rely on elements that can be added using the CKEditor.

e.g. (within the loop, in a theme template file)

```
<div id="myContentDiv">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Then your CSS:

```
#myContentDiv p {

}

#myContentDiv ul {

}
```

etc.

Comment: I thought this might be the way, but what if you have a non standard layout, like 3 columns of content for example? Or is it doomed to be plain and simple?

Comment: @Phill it's not doomed to be plain and simple, but if you want to use three columns, you're going to have to work that into your template. If you want to put nothing in those columns than standard Wordpress post elements (e.g. `the_post_thumbnail();` or `the_content();` etc.) then you can already do that. If you want to have multiple "content" areas, where they can customize text, images, etc., you'll have to add new post_meta, then alter the admin page editor layout to give them the ability to input those new post_meta fields within the page editor.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options that comes to me right now:

1. Use jquery plugins to get columns (which is pretty bad IMHO)
2. Use a plugin with shortcodes (so you wrap each column with them), which is good but user may screw it up yet
3. Use custom fields (like one text area "Right column content", then you have another text area "Left column content" and so on)

All these 3 are quite easy to implement! :)

[]'s

Comment: Can they format the content in custom fields? Or should each field have their own CSS style? How would they go about bolding some text in a paragraph?

Comment: Yeah, you may have as many TinyMCE fields as you want. If you want a quick solution I'll recommend you custom field template plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/